# How do I format longer sentences in html rather than a word / line?

Tags: html, css

[image]

I am a new user of html and css and I have a school assignment that requires us to make a website from scratch. I have come across multiple errors. Please help!

Where it says "RTX 3090" in one of the squares, I'd like it so that the text can come in longer lines rather than being one word per line.

I want:

```
RTX 3090
```

What it does:

```
RTX 
3090
```

Here is the code:

```css
    /*Tickets Section*/

#tickets {
  flex-direction: column;
  text-align: center;
  max-width: 1500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 100px 0;
}

#ticketstop .sectiontitle h1{
  font-size: 2rem;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: black;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: .2rem;
  text-align: center;
  opacity: 100;

}
.sectiontitle span{
  color: #347f7d;
}

#tickets .sectiontitle{
  font-size: 2rem;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: white;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: .2rem;
  text-align: center;
  opacity: 100;

}

#tickets .sectiontitle span{
  color: #347f7d;
}

#tickets .ticketsbottom{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin-top: 10px;
  transform: translate(0,-30%);
}

#tickets .ticketsitem {

  flex-basis: 15%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-image: url(./ticket.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  margin: 5px 1%;
  position: relative;
  z-index: +1;

}

#tickets .ticketsitem::after{
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left:0;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(60deg, #26323c 0%, #485563 100%);
  opacity: .8;
  z-index: -1;
  border-radius: 10px;

}

#tickets .ticketsbottom .icon{
  height: 80px;
  width: 80px;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
}

#tickets .ticketsbottom .icon img{
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  transform: translate(-50%,-70%);
  width: 350px;
  position: absolute;

}

#tickets .ticketsitem h2{
  font-size: 2rem;
  color: white;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

#tickets .ticketsitem p{
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.4rem;
  line-height: 1.9rem;

}
```

```html
 <section id="tickets">
    <div id="tickets container">


      <div class="ticketsbottom">
        <div class="ticketsitem">
          <div class="icon">
            <img src="hot1.png"/>
          </div>
          <h2>MYTHIC BUILD</h2>
          <p>RTX 3090</p>
        </div>
        <div class="ticketsitem">
          <div class="icon">
            <img src="#"/>
          </div>
          <h2>LEGENDARY BUILD</h2>
          <p>RTX 3080</p>
        </div>
        <div class="ticketsitem">
          <div class="icon">
            <img src="https://img.icons8.com/fluent/48/000000/bronze-ore.png"/>
          </div>
          <h2>EPIC BUILD</h2>
          <p>RTX 3070</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To prevent spaces from breaking, use `white-space: nowrap;`.
Like this:

```css
   /*Tickets Section*/

   #tickets {
     flex-direction: column;
     text-align: center;
     max-width: 1500px;
     margin: 0 auto;
     padding: 100px 0;
   }

   #ticketstop .sectiontitle h1 {
     font-size: 2rem;
     font-weight: 300;
     color: black;
     margin-bottom: 10px;
     text-transform: uppercase;
     letter-spacing: .2rem;
     text-align: center;
     opacity: 100;

   }

   .sectiontitle span {
     color: #347f7d;
   }

   #tickets .sectiontitle {
     font-size: 2rem;
     font-weight: 300;
     color: white;
     margin-bottom: 10px;
     text-transform: uppercase;
     letter-spacing: .2rem;
     text-align: center;
     opacity: 100;

   }

   #tickets .sectiontitle span {
     color: #347f7d;
   }

   #tickets .ticketsbottom {
     display: flex;
     align-items: center;
     justify-content: center;
     flex-wrap: wrap;
     margin-top: 10px;
     transform: translate(0, -30%);
   }

   #tickets .ticketsitem {

     flex-basis: 15%;
     display: flex;
     align-items: center;
     justify-content: center;
     flex-direction: column;
     padding: 10px;
     border-radius: 10px;
     background-image: url(./ticket.jpg);
     background-size: cover;
     margin: 5px 1%;
     position: relative;
     z-index: +1;

   }

   #tickets .ticketsitem::after {
     content: '';
     position: absolute;
     left: 0;
     top: 0;
     height: 100%;
     width: 100%;
     background-image: linear-gradient(60deg, #26323c 0%, #485563 100%);
     opacity: .8;
     z-index: -1;
     border-radius: 10px;

   }

   #tickets .ticketsbottom .icon {
     height: 80px;
     width: 80px;
     margin-bottom: 25px;
   }

   #tickets .ticketsbottom .icon img {
     margin-left: auto;
     margin-right: auto;
     transform: translate(-50%, -70%);
     width: 350px;
     position: absolute;

   }

   #tickets .ticketsitem h2 {
     font-size: 2rem;
     color: white;
     margin-bottom: 10px;
     text-transform: uppercase;
   }

   #tickets .ticketsitem p {
     color: white;
     text-align: center;
     font-size: 1.4rem;
     line-height: 1.9rem;
     white-space: nowrap;
   }
```

```html
 <section id="tickets">
   <div id="tickets container">
     <div class="ticketsbottom">
       <div class="ticketsitem">
         <div class="icon">
           <img src="hot1.png" />
         </div>
         <h2>MYTHIC BUILD</h2>
         <p>RTX 3090</p>
       </div>
       <div class="ticketsitem">
         <div class="icon">
           <img src="#" />
         </div>
         <h2>LEGENDARY BUILD</h2>
         <p>RTX 3080</p>
       </div>
       <div class="ticketsitem">
         <div class="icon">
           <img src="https://img.icons8.com/fluent/48/000000/bronze-ore.png" />
         </div>
         <h2>EPIC BUILD</h2>
         <p>RTX 3070</p>
       </div>
     </div>
   </div>
 </section>
```